# Jquery custom-select plugin unable to select option with code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to use this searchable [jquery.customSelect](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect) plugin. Now I am trying to set an option programmatically by the val. and here is my code

```
 var mainProjectDropdown = $jq("#mainProjectId").customselect();
            mainProjectDropdown.val(mainProjectId).trigger('render');
```

The second way:

```
 var mainProjectDropdown = $jq("#mainProjectId").customselect();
            mainProjectDropdown.val(mainProjectId).trigger('update');
```

But both are not working. Here are the links which shows me how to do this work:
[1](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect/issues/78) , [2](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect/issues/22)

```js
const mainProjectId = "ID5";
$(function() {
  var mainProjectDropdown = $("#mainProjectId").customSelect()

  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    mainProjectDropdown.val(mainProjectId).trigger('render');
    // mainProjectDropdown.val(mainProjectId).trigger('update');
    // mainProjectDropdown.value = mainProjectId;
  })

});
```

```css
span.customSelect {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: #fff url(http://i48.tinypic.com/2u7rpec.png) right center no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #555;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px;
  width: 175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.customSelect/0.5.1/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>

<select id="mainProjectId">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: No, they are the same and this plugin was implemented earlier

Comment: Yeah i am using jquery.customSelect. Thanks

Comment: But your code snipper is not working. customSelect property in document.querySelector('.customSelect').customSelect is not recognizing. Throwing error

Comment: So my suggestion is to use select2 which is last changed 25 days ago. Your plugin is last changed 3 years ago

Comment: I have added my code there

Comment: I have tried your code. Still the same problem.

Comment: Yeah you tried best. but one more thing i want to share that when i am opening the dropdown the selected option is correctly selected.